# Resample dates weekly

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm trying to resample my datetime index data weekly. For that I used:

```
data.resample('W').last()
```

However, the dates that appear are indeed weekly sampled, however the dates sometimes are at dates that did not exist in the original data. Is it possible to force the resampling in order to get only dates that existed in the original data?

Comment: Pandas `Index` object support the same methods that `set` does (`.difference()`, etc).  That might not be the most Pythonic way, but it can probably get you what you need

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new column, `date`, which is the same as the index, then `df.resample('W').last()` will also return the last date in each resampling group. You could the set these dates as the new index. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2019)

N = 40
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,2)), columns=list('AB'), index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='B'))
df['date'] = df.index
result = df.resample('W').last()
#             A  B       date
# 2000-01-09  7  8 2000-01-07
# 2000-01-16  4  0 2000-01-14
# 2000-01-23  3  5 2000-01-21
# 2000-01-30  3  7 2000-01-28
# 2000-02-06  6  1 2000-02-04
# 2000-02-13  5  5 2000-02-11
# 2000-02-20  2  7 2000-02-18
# 2000-02-27  9  0 2000-02-25

result = result.set_index('date')
```

yields

```
In [154]: result
Out[154]: 
            A  B
date            
2000-01-07  7  8
2000-01-14  4  0
2000-01-21  3  5
2000-01-28  3  7
2000-02-04  6  1
2000-02-11  5  5
2000-02-18  2  7
2000-02-25  9  0
```